# Как в IntelliJ IDEA отеследить скорость выполнения кода?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как в IntelliJ IDEA отеследить время, за которое выполняется мой код?

Comment: Создать перед вашей операцией Date и получить в мс разницу после выполнения.

Comment: Вам профайлер подойдет? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать класс Date чтобы получить время до и после в миллисекундах.
Я уверен найдётся более изящное решение, сильно не минусите )

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    
            long d = new Date().getTime();
            //Ваш код
            doSomething();
            //конец вашего кода
            long e = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println(e-d);
    
        }
    
        public static void doSomething(){
            int count=0;
            while (count<200){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Измерять время исполнения кода через

```
LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.now();
// some code
LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Плохая затея, если код не исполняется хотя бы несколько секунд, на даже при этом результат будет зависеть от состояния jvm в момент замера и других факторов. Советую ознакомиться с докладами Алексея Шипелёва про производительность в java. На ютубе их множество. Для измерения времени выполнения кода стоит использовать специальные фреймворки, например, JMH https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.now();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
    
    LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.now();

    System.out.println(Duration.between(from, to).toMillis());

}
```

Код выводит в консоль время выполнения цикла по добавлению 1 000 000 элементов в список в миллисекундах.